Why console.logs are not colorized using colorette or chalk in a Firebase project on my Mac?
I was trying to colorize the logs on terminal and it worked for simple NodeJS project both on my Windows PC and Mac, but for a Firebase project on my Mac, it is not working (no issue on Windows).
I tried using Warp, Terminal.app, and VSCode's ZSH. I tried switching packages from colorette to chalk but didn't work.
Screenshot of the issue

Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to copy your code and instructions and run it for ourselves.  Also it's not clear what you mean by "firebase project".  What exactly are you running, how are you running it, and how are you observing the results?

@DougStevenson, thanks for the comment . but to be specific, I am using firebase cloud functions, locally running the server and trying to see the logs on my termnial. I tried colorette and chalk to colorize the logs but it was not working on my mac. There was no issue with the code as the same code worked on my windows and mac also with other nodejs project. btw, check the answer section. it is solved now.

Try using 'ansi-colors'. I'm using it in firebase project on mac and it works fine.

you saved me. thanks!
